# Can't add data via postman

Tags: postman, codeigniter-4

I want to make crud in postman with codeigniter4. But I have a problem when I will add data with post function an error occurs in postman like the picture I sent.
[This is a picture of the Error section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttVV7.png)

controller Konven.php

```
class Konven extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Get all Konven
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $model = new KonvenModel();
        return $this->getResponse(
            [
                'message' => 'Product Convent retrieved',
                'produk_konven' => $model->findAll()
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Create a new KOnven
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $rules = [
            'nama_menu' => 'required',
            'tipe_id' => 'required'
        ];

        $input = $this->getRequestInput($this->request);

        if (!$this->validateRequest($input, $rules)) {
            return $this->getResponse(
                    $this->validator->getErrors(),
                    ResponseInterface::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
                );
        }

        $konvenEmail = $input['nama_menu'];
        $model = new KonvenModel();
        $model->save($input);
        $produk_konven = $model->where('nama_menu', $konvenEmail)->first();

        return $this->getResponse(
            [
                'message' => 'Product Convent added successfully',
                'produk_konven' => $produk_konven
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get a single client by ID
     */
    public function show($produk_konven_id)
    {
        try {
            $model = new KonvenModel();
            $produk_konven = $model->findKonvenById($produk_konven_id);

            return $this->getResponse(
                [
                    'message' => 'Product Convent retrieved successfully',
                    'produk_konven' => $produk_konven
                ]
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->getResponse(
                [
                    'message' => 'Could not find product convent for specified ID'
                ],
                ResponseInterface::HTTP_NOT_FOUND
            );
        }
    }
```

model KonvenModel.php

```
class KonvenModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'produk_konven';
    protected $allowedFields = [
        'nama_menu',
        'status',
        'tipe_id'
    ];
    protected $updatedField = 'updated_at';

    public function findKonvenById($produk_konven_id)
    {
        $produk_konven = $this
            ->asArray()
            ->where(['produk_konven_id' => $produk_konven_id])
            ->first();
        $produk_konven->join('tipe', 'produk_konven.tipe_id = tipe.tipe_id');
        $produk_konven->orderBy("produk_konven_id", "asc");
        if (!$produk_konven) throw new Exception('Could not find client for specified ID');

        return $produk_konven;
    }
    
}
```

Can friends help me overcome the obstacles that I am experiencing?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be 

searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: @Vickel In postman there is an error like this:     
    "title": "ErrorException",
    "type": "ErrorException",
    "code": 500,
    "message": "pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  column &quot;id&quot; does not exist\nLINE 3: WHERE &quot;id&quot; IS NULL\n

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error text from your comment into your question, so folks won't have to read the comments to get all the information needed to help.  Thanks.

Comment: What is `getRequestInput()`?